# I don't manage to create bevel in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, cs4

This is what I have tried but not succeeded:

```
generateBevel(playBarBackground);

function generateBevel(myMC)
{
    var myBevel:BevelFilter = new BevelFilter();
    myBevel.type = BitmapFilterType.INNER;
    myBevel.angle = 45;
    myBevel.distance = 5;
    myBevel.highlightColor = 0x666666;
    myBevel.shadowColor = 0x000000;
    myBevel.blurX = 5;
    myBevel.blurY = 5;
    myBevel.strength = 100;
    myMC.filters = [myBevel];
}
```

I have also tried to do this without function having the code where the function call is situated but no luck. I just would like to do things with function because I have two movie clips that I want to modify.

Comment: can you add `trace(myMC.filters);` at the end of your function ? what is the result ?

Comment: it's working but your values are so small you probably don't even see it.

Comment: Trace result: [object BevelFilter]